# Should I instantiate variable that will hold the return type from a method call?

Tags: c#

I have a CarSpecs class and I have a service with a method called GetCarSpecs who's return type is of CarSpecs. Should I call the method like this:

```
CarSpecs carSpecs = service.GetCarSpecs();
```

Or is there a reason why it would make sense to instantiate the CarSpecs class first before calling the method in the service like this:

```
CarSpecs carSpecs = new CarSpecs();
carSpecs = service.GetCarSpecs();
```

Comment: There is no reason to do the second.

Comment: The first example is the correct one. The second creates a useless reference to an instance of CarSpecs that is immediately replaced by the reference returned by your method

Comment: Basically, there is no need to create a new instance before calling a method

Comment: No need to create an instance as in the second example. And one more thing if you are not sure about the return type of the method just use "var" keyword. 
e.g. var carSpecs = service.GetCarSpecs();

Comment: Assuming `CarSpecs` is a reference type (aka, a class) then `carSpecs` is simply a reference variable.  If you just say `CarSpecs carSpecs`, it gets initialized to `null` (though the compiler will complain that it's uninitialized if you try to use it). When you `CarSpecs carSpecs = new CarSpecs();`, new memory will be allocated, a new object constructed in that mem, and `carSpecs` will get initialized with a ref to the new obj.  In your next line, `carSpecs` gets reassigned, and the original object has no references, so it will be garbage collected.  All you are doing is creating garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no need to instantiate  an additional object that wil just be discarded.